# React initiates the state to default after calling the API with DEBOUNCING

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, debouncing

I created a simple "notes app" by just passing the props and callback functions to the child and nested child components. My CRUD is working fine when I update the note on each keystroke. However, when I call the API using the **Debouncing** concept, the App.js forgets the state and re-initiates it to the default value.

here is the following code -

**App.js**

```
 const addNote = async (note) => {
    const newNote = await CreateNote(note); // this is API call
    let newNotes = [...notes]; // notes is state - array of note object
    newNotes.unshift(newNote);
    setNotes(newNotes);
    setActiveNote(newNote);
  };
```

**note-editor.js**

```
    const handleNoteChange = (e) => {
        let newNote = { ...activeNote, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
        activateNote(newNote);
        //addOrUpdateNote(newNote); // this code is working and updating the list correctly
        optimizedAddOrUpdateNote(newNote); // this code re-initiates the "notes" state in App.js to default []
    };


    const addOrUpdateNote = (note) => {
        if (!note.createdDate) {
            if (note.title.trim() || note.body.trim()) {
                addNote(note); // this is coming from app.js as prop callback
            }
        } else {
            updateNote(note); // this is coming from app.js as prop callback
        }
    };



    const debounce = (func) => {
       let timer;
       return function(...args) {
        const context = this;
        if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            timer = null;
            func.apply(context, args);
        }, 500);
      }
    }

    const optimizedAddOrUpdateNote = useCallback(debounce(addOrUpdateNote), []);

    return (
             <div className={Classes["note-editor-body"]}>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    name='title'
                    placeholder='title...'
                    onChange={handleNoteChange} //trying to call the API using debounciing
                    value={activeNote.title}
                />
                <textarea
                    maxLength={AppConstants.NOTE_BODY_CHARACTER_LIMIT}
                    name='body'
                    placeholder='add your notes here'
                    onChange={handleNoteChange} //trying to call the API using debounciing
                    value={activeNote.body.slice(
                        0,
                        AppConstants.NOTE_BODY_CHARACTER_LIMIT
                    )}
                />
            </div>
         )
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: From which library are you importing debounce from?

Comment: Updated the code to include debounce function declaration @Poku

Answer (score 0):

React has its own build in debounce functionality with useDeferredValue(). There a good article about it here: https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/2022-05/use-deferred-value/.

So in your case you could replace your optimizedAddOrUpdateNote function with a useEffect hook that have a dependency on the deferredValue. Something like this:

```
import { useState, useDeferredValue, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [note, setNote] = useState("");
  const deferredNote = useDeferredValue(note);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("call api with deferred value");
  }, [deferredNote]);

  function handleNoteChange(e) {
    setNote(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" value={note} onChange={handleNoteChange} />
      <p>{note}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution, didn't work. Please also tell me what's wrong with my code, and why it's re-initiating?

Comment: What doesn't work with this example? I supplied you this because your code is hard to read. Maybe we could help if you did a codesandbox.io example were we can reproduce. But generally there are libraries implement useDebounce hooks. Ex https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-debounce if you don't want to have more control over the timeout duration. But again the example above should do the trick using only react.